# Windows Phone 7 Downloading Files

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to write an app that allows me to download quicken files from my Wells Fargo account. The file is just a .qfx file that downloads after a form post. Is there any way using either the WebBrowser control or some other method to download such a file to my phone into my app's isolated storage?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using webclient class in windows phone. All you have to do is open up the stream  for a specific url and then start writing the contents that you receive to your local storage. This is the highest level of information that I could provide for file download.

Take a look at the `Webclient` class [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.95).aspx ] in windows phone 7 and `OpenReadAsync()` [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144211(v=vs.95).aspx ] method of the same for further details.